# how to formatting numeric values to the 3rd digit whilst it evens it to 2nd digit in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, formatting, numeric, enterprise-guide

I am trying to solve a problem of numeric formatting in SAS EG and I hope you could offer me some support.

Basically, the variables with numeric data I receive have 3 decimal digits, but I got asked to convert these data into a format which displays the 3 digits but it evens them to the 2nd digit.

What I need to achieve is something like this:

```
prize_old = 14543.567  prize_new = 14543.570
prize_old = 647473.543 prize_new = 647473.540
```

Moreover, if you see the code they asked me to edit, the final variables prize_string_n are strings, resulting from the concatenation between the sign and the number, therefore I need to intervene before the cats function.

```
data new;
set old;
prize_01 = sum(effect_2021_1, effect_trash_T_2021_1, effect_trash_C_2021_1);
prize_02 = sum(effect_2021_2, effect_trash_T_2021_2, effect_trash_C_2021_2);
prize_03 = sum(effect_2021_3, effect_trash_T_2021_3, effect_trash_C_2021_3);
prize_04 = sum(effect_2021_4, effect_trash_T_2021_4, effect_trash_C_2021_4);
prize_05 = sum(effect_2021_5, effect_trash_T_2021_5, effect_trash_C_2021_5);
prize_06 = sum(effect_2021_6, effect_trash_T_2021_6, effect_trash_C_2021_6);
prize_07 = sum(effect_2021_7, effect_trash_T_2021_7, effect_trash_C_2021_7);
prize_08 = sum(effect_2021_8, effect_trash_T_2021_8, effect_trash_C_2021_8);
prize_09 = sum(effect_2021_9, effect_trash_T_2021_9, effect_trash_C_2021_9);
prize_10 = sum(effect_2021_10, effect_trash_T_2021_10, effect_trash_C_2021_10);
prize_11 = sum(effect_2021_11, effect_trash_T_2021_11, effect_trash_C_2021_11);
prize_12 = sum(effect_2021_12, effect_trash_T_2021_12, effect_trash_C_2021_12);

if prize_01 = . then prize_01 = 0;
if prize_02 = . then prize_02 = 0;
if prize_03 = . then prize_03 = 0;
if prize_04 = . then prize_04 = 0;
if prize_05 = . then prize_05 = 0;
if prize_06 = . then prize_06 = 0;
if prize_07 = . then prize_07 = 0;
if prize_08 = . then prize_08 = 0;
if prize_09 = . then prize_09 = 0;
if prize_10 = . then prize_10 = 0;
if prize_11 = . then prize_11 = 0;
if prize_12 = . then prize_12 = 0;

if prize_01 >= 0 then SIGN_01 = '+';
if prize_02 >= 0 then SIGN_02 = '+';
if prize_03 >= 0 then SIGN_03 = '+';
if prize_04 >= 0 then SIGN_04 = '+';
if prize_05 >= 0 then SIGN_05 = '+';
if prize_06 >= 0 then SIGN_06 = '+';
if prize_07 >= 0 then SIGN_07 = '+';
if prize_08 >= 0 then SIGN_08 = '+';
if prize_09 >= 0 then SIGN_09 = '+';
if prize_10 >= 0 then SIGN_10 = '+';
if prize_11 >= 0 then SIGN_11 = '+';
if prize_12 >= 0 then SIGN_12 = '+';

if prize_01 < 0 then SIGN_01 = '-';
if prize_02 < 0 then SIGN_02 = '-';
if prize_03 < 0 then SIGN_03 = '-';
if prize_04 < 0 then SIGN_04 = '-';
if prize_05 < 0 then SIGN_05 = '-';
if prize_06 < 0 then SIGN_06 = '-';
if prize_07 < 0 then SIGN_07 = '-';
if prize_08 < 0 then SIGN_08 = '-';
if prize_09 < 0 then SIGN_09 = '-';
if prize_10 < 0 then SIGN_10 = '-';
if prize_11 < 0 then SIGN_11 = '-';
if prize_12 < 0 then SIGN_12 = '-';

prize_ABS_01 = abs(prize_01);
prize_ABS_02 = abs(prize_02);
prize_ABS_03 = abs(prize_03);
prize_ABS_04 = abs(prize_04);
prize_ABS_05 = abs(prize_05);
prize_ABS_06 = abs(prize_06);
prize_ABS_07 = abs(prize_07);
prize_ABS_08 = abs(prize_08);
prize_ABS_09 = abs(prize_09);
prize_ABS_10 = abs(prize_10);
prize_ABS_11 = abs(prize_11);
prize_ABS_12 = abs(prize_12);

prize_STRING_01 = cats(SIGN_01, vvalue(prize_ABS_01));
prize_STRING_02 = cats(SIGN_02, vvalue(prize_ABS_02));
prize_STRING_03 = cats(SIGN_03, vvalue(prize_ABS_03));
prize_STRING_04 = cats(SIGN_04, vvalue(prize_ABS_04));
prize_STRING_05 = cats(SIGN_05, vvalue(prize_ABS_05));
prize_STRING_06 = cats(SIGN_06, vvalue(prize_ABS_06));
prize_STRING_07 = cats(SIGN_07, vvalue(prize_ABS_07));
prize_STRING_08 = cats(SIGN_08, vvalue(prize_ABS_08));
prize_STRING_09 = cats(SIGN_09, vvalue(prize_ABS_09));
prize_STRING_10 = cats(SIGN_10, vvalue(prize_ABS_10));
prize_STRING_11 = cats(SIGN_11, vvalue(prize_ABS_11));
prize_STRING_12 = cats(SIGN_12, vvalue(prize_ABS_12));
run;
```

any suggestions how to deal it? thanks in advance for the help :))

Answer (score 0):

First - you don't need to use a string for this, you can do this all with a format - but here is how I would do what you're doing.

1. Use arrays.  PLEASE don't write this code 12 times, it's error prone and wasteful.
2. Simplify.  If you always want the sum to be 0 if it otherwise would be missing, include 0 in the sum!  Use `ifc` which is the ternary if - basically, if it's true return 2nd argument, if false return 3rd argument.
3. You can `round` to the right place value, then `put`.

Here's the example code:

```
data old;
  call streaminit(7);
  array effect[12] effect_2021_01-effect_2021_12;
  array effect_t[12] effect_trash_t_2021_01-effect_trash_t_2021_12;
  array effect_c[12] effect_trash_c_2021_01-effect_trash_c_2021_12;
  do _n_ = 1 to 10;
    do i = 1 to dim(effect);
      effect[i] = rand('Uniform')*100;
      effect_T[i] = rand('Uniform')*100;
      effect_C[i] = rand('Uniform')*100;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data new;
  set old;
  length prize_string_01-prize_String_12 $24;
  array prize[12] prize_01-prize_12;
  array prize_str[12] $ prize_string_01-prize_string_12;
  array effect[12] effect_2021_:;
  array effect_t[12] effect_trash_t_2021_:;
  array effect_c[12] effect_trash_c_2021_:;

  do i = 1 to dim(prize);
    prize[i] = sum(effect[i],effect_t[i],effect_c[i],0);
    sign = ifc(prize[i] ge 0, '+', '-');
    prize_str[i] = cats(sign,put(abs(round(prize[i],.01)),12.3));
  end;
run;
```

However - I would use a picture format, perhaps, though I'm not sure you can get the trailing zero in that; but you probably can.  Here's the start of one, in any event, this at least does the prefix...

```
proc format;
  picture twodecf(round )
    low-<0 = '0000.99' ( prefix='-' )
    0-high = '0000.99' ( prefix='+' )
    ;
quit;
```

That could then be applied to the value and either CATS'ed on to a zero, at least applying the sign for you automatically, or perhaps someone can come up with how to add the extra zero.